# How execute a task inside doLast in Gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-task

I am trying to create a zip using gradle task but while running inside `doLast{}` , it's throwing error saying : **> Cannot call Task.dependsOn(Object...) on task ':app:testZip' after task has started execution.**

**MyCode :**

```
doLast {

    testDir.eachWithIndex { a, i ->

        def dir = "${testDir[i]}"
        def dirName = "${testDirName[i]}"

       dependsOn tasks.create("testZip$c", Zip) {
            from dir
            baseName dirName
            destinationDir(file("$dir"))
        }

        c++
    } }
```

I don't find solution to this issue, please let me know, how can i run **Zip** task inside `doLast{}`

Answer (score 0):

The error is being thrown because you are trying to create a new Task after the configuration phase has completed.  Some possible solutions are to; remove the doLast() call, define a zip task outside of your doLast() or move zip logic into a method.